# "Dois" e "2" não são quatro?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Existe um adjectivo/substantivo que signifique escrever 'dois' ou escrever '2'? Está relacionado com a diferença entre cardinal e ordinal?

Obrigado

Comment: Mas queres saber porque dois e dois não são quatro ou só a diferença entre cardinal e ordinal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando escrevo "dois", digo que escrevo o número **por extenso**.

Os números cardinais são um, dois, três etc., escritos por extenso ou em notação numérica (1, 2, 3 etc.). Os numerais ordinais são primeiro, segundo, terceiro etc. (em notação numérica, 1º, 2º, 3º etc.).

Não há relação entre escrever os números por extenso ou não e os conceitos de "cardinal" e "ordinal".

Comment: Faltou explicar que como são escritos os ordinais